# how to make a hidden graph work with numerical labels in flot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden, flot, label

I am trying to make a program that draws in FLOT some beam stresses such as shear and moments, but I have trouble when adding a hidden graph with a checkbox. The problem is as follows:

Everything works fine until I try to hide any line or points of the graph. When I hide anything, the numerical labels become -0.00 (as it is literally coded).

How could I fix it?

I am really stuck at the moment.

This is the code

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo Flot Threshold Bueno</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.threshold.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.flot.hiddengraphs.js"></script>

 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Ejemplo Flot Threshold Bueno</h1>
<CENTER>

    <div id="grafico" style="width:800px;height:500px;"></div>

</CENTER>

<CENTER>
        <p id="choices">Show:</p>
</CENTER>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

  //la variable plot es el gráfico incluyendo el cartelito-leyenda y sus valores.
  //no quitar esta var nunca!!
var plot;

  //declaro las variables que intervienen.
    var cort = [], flec = []; viga = []; apoyos = [];
    var l=10;
    var p=10;
    var i=0;
    var num_apoyos=2;

    for (i = 0; i < num_apoyos; i++) {
        apoyos.push([i*l, -0.65]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i += 0.05) {

        viga.push([i*l/40, 0]);
        cort.push([i*l/40, -p/2]);
        flec.push([i*l/40, -p*l*i/(2*40)]);

    }

    for (i = 20; i <= 40; i += 0.05) {

        viga.push([i*l/40, 0]);
        cort.push([i*l/40, p/2]);
        flec.push([i*l/40, -p*l*(1-i/40)/2]);

    }


  //Ahora se prepara cada variable como un objeto diferente,
  //y así se pinta cada una por separado.

var dataset = {

"viga":{
    data: viga,
    color: "#000000",
    label: "Viga",
},
"apoyos":{
    data: apoyos,
    lines: { show: false },
    points: { show: true, radius: 5, symbol: "triangle" },
    label: "Apoyos",
},
"flector":{
    data: flec,
    color: "#00FFFF",
    threshold: { below: 0, color: "#990048" },
    label: "Flector = -0.00",
},
"cortante":{
    data: cort,
    color: "#FF0000",
    threshold: { below: 0, color: "#00EB6E" },
    label: "Cortante = -0.00",
},

};

        // hard-code color indices to prevent them from shifting as
        // lines are turned on/off
        var i = 0;
        $.each(dataset, function(key, val) {
            val.color = i;
            ++i;
        });

      // insert checkboxes
        var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
        $.each(dataset, function(key, val) {
            // qué es append? Sirve para insertar el nombre del checkbox.
            choiceContainer.append('<br/><input type="checkbox" name="' + key +
                                   '" checked="checked" id= "id' + key + '">' +
                                   '<label for="id' + key + '">'
                                    + val.label + '</label>');
        });
        choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);


        function plotAccordingToChoices() {
            var dta = [];

            choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr("name");
                if (key && dataset[key]){
                    dta.push(dataset[key]);
                }
            });

            if (dta.length > 0)
                plot=$.plot($("#grafico"), dta, {
                    yaxis: {  },
                    xaxis: {  },
                    crosshair: { mode: "x,y" },
                    shadowSize: 5,
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        },
                });
        };

        plotAccordingToChoices();

    var previousPoint = null;

    var legends = $("#grafico .legendLabel");
    legends.each(function () {
        // fix the widths so they do not jump around
        $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
    });

        var updateLegendTimeout = null;
        var latestPosition = null;

        function updateLegend() {
            updateLegendTimeout = null;

            var pos = latestPosition;

            var axes = plot.getAxes();
            if (pos.x < axes.xaxis.min || pos.x > axes.xaxis.max ||
                pos.y < axes.yaxis.min || pos.y > axes.yaxis.max)
                return;

            var j, k, dataset = plot.getData();
            for (j = 0; j < dataset.length; ++j) {
                var series = dataset[j];

                // find the nearest points, x-wise
                for (k = 0; k < series.data.length; ++k)
                    if (series.data[k][0] > pos.x)
                        break;

                // now interpolate
                var y, p1 = series.data[k - 1], p2 = series.data[k];
                if (p1 == null)
                    y = p2[1];
                else if (p2 == null)
                    y = p1[1];
                else
                    y = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);

                legends.eq(j).text(series.label.replace(/=.*/, "= " + y.toFixed(2)));
            }
    }



  // Esto no sé lo que es todavía

    $("#grafico").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        latestPosition = pos;
        if (!updateLegendTimeout)
            updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend, 50);

    });

});

document.write("El flector vale: ");
document.wirte();
document.write("El cortante vale: ");
document.write();

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle on that?

Comment: I don't know what a jsfiddle is? But I'm gonna investigate about it

Comment: open this link: http://jsfiddle.net/, put your css, html and javascript at it's place and Hit Save link on top menu bar, and then copy the link of that page and paste it here.

Comment: ok. wati a sec. Thnks so much for the help!

Comment: This is the link you wanted:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/58Mww/

Comment: Gr8 job, now open this link http://jsfiddle.net/58Mww/2/ and see in the left, you can find **External Resources**, click on that, and add your jsfiles one by one there. like __jquery.flot.js__ and so on...

Comment: then click __UPDATE__ on the top menu, and paste the URL here again...

Comment: I got it:  http://jsfiddle.net/58Mww/3/

Comment: I can not see any graph in it?

Comment: I see. But when I open it in Chrome it shows a graph. It's the fiddle which cannot show it

Comment: Including the whole code that I first attached when making the question in TextPad and opening it whith Chrome, the graph is just over the checkboxes which started with "Show:". Somehow, fiddle cannot make the graph

Comment: I think it could be that my code includes too many attributes and fiddle can't manage with it